# Random looking Gray Codes or Hamiltonian Cycles on Hypercubes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, random-walk

Cyclic Gray codes come in many flavors and correspond 1-1 to Hamiltonian cycles on hypercubes. **I would like to find a type that looks like a random walk on the hypercube.** In a sense this is an oxymoron, since a real random walk will almost certainly not produce a Hamiltonian cycle. However, it might be possible to produce Gray codes where such that most segments up to some length look sufficiently random. Clearly the self avoiding property of a Hamiltonian path quickly becomes strong evidence of non randomness, but my critrea are not very strong I just need something where the structure is not completely obvious.

Comment: After reading the text, I could not locate a central question. Here are some questions: 1. What is the average length of a random walk before we visit a vertex again? 2. If the length of a self-avoiding walk is the random variable, what is the probability distribution?

Comment: The question is "What type of Gray code looks most like a random walk, at least over short distances."

Comment: What do you mean by "looks most like a random walk"? What rule determines that? I'd try just picking a random Gray code.

Comment: I figure that if anybody has looked into this question then they probably also came up with better randomness metric than I am likely to. So I am happy to take theirs. Picking a random Gray code from the space of all n-bit Gray codes is easier said than done, but if there is a tractable algorithm for that, I will take that too.

Comment: Any single choice of construction or algorithm will surely have some pattern to it. I posit that maybe you would do better to look for a way to sample uniformly from the set of *all* cyclic Gray codes; an instance drawn from this distribution is then likely to look pretty random.